# create while loop with cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

how to create sql server cte from a while loop
my loop like this

```
  declare @ind as int
  declare @code as nvarchar
  set @ind  = 0
   while @ind < 884
  begin
    select @ind  = @ind  + 1
    --here execute Procedure 
        --and set return value to variable 
    set @code = cast (@ind   as nvarchar)
  end
```

Comment: is a recursive cte definitely needed? - it is a structure I'd use when trying to do running totals or walking down a tree like data structure ....for a simple loop `while` is spot on.

Comment: You need the result as table or as a single string?

Comment: You can't call a stored procedure as part of a query* - you'd need to expand the definition of the stored procedure into this query - is that something you want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need table:

```
;WITH Sec(Number) AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM Sec
    WHERE Number < 884
) 

SELECT * FROM Sec
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

If you need one string:

```
;WITH Sec(Number) AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM Sec
    WHERE Number < 884
) 

SELECT STUFF(a.[Str], 1, 1, '')
FROM
(
    SELECT (SELECT ',' + CAST(Number AS NVARCHAR(3)) 
    FROM Sec
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','varchar(max)') AS [Str] 
) AS a
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: this is just awesome.

Answer (score 6):

Below query selects values from 0 to 884:

```
;WITH T(Num)AS
(
    SELECT 0 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Num+1 FROM T WHERE T.Num < 884
)SELECT Num FROM T 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```