# Table-Valued-Function with cte

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I was trying to loop through a cte with a given parameters From and To Date. I read this [create while loop with cte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929165/create-while-loop-with-cte) and tried it on my query but the result shows only the start date and the next date.

```
DECLARE @fromdate datetime
DECLARE @todate datetime
SET @fromdate='2013-07-23'
SET @todate='2013-07-24'

;with dates(num) as (
  select @fromdate as fromdate
  union all
  select @fromdate + 1
  from dates
  where dates.num < @todate      
 ),
    T(employee_id,actualogin,actuallogout) as (
     select d.*
     from dates cross apply
     dbo.ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE(dates.num) d
 )
 SELECT * FROM T
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: posted my solution with the help of Gordon's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to first get the list of dates and then apply the function:

```
with dates as (
      select @fromdate as date
      union all
      select date + 1
      from dates
      where dates.date < @todate
    ),
    T(employee_id,actualogin,actuallogout) as (
     select t.*
     from dates cross apply
          dbo.ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE(dates.date)
    )
```

Comment: just tweak your statement, it creates redundant date. "where dates.date < @todate". Thanks, you give me a solution.