# Variables Declaration, CTEs, and While Loops in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, while-loop, common-table-expression

So I might be stuck at something very trivial but can't figure out how to make it work. I create a 2 blocks of code that work in SQL but I have some problems with the date variable declaration in Oracle SQL.

I had write access to the SQL database when I create these codes so I did a 'Insert Into' to create temp tables. I don't have write access anymore. So I am using CTEs for it.

The original code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Startdate Datetime = '2021-Jun-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @Enddate Datetime = '2021-Jun-30 00:00:00.000' 

Insert into Temp1
select ...
from ...

WHILE Startdate <= Enddate
BEGIN
Insert into Temp2
select ...
from (Temp 1)
left join
select ...

set @startdate=dateadd(d,1,@startdate)
end;
```

With my new code, I have made the following adjustmnets:

```
VARIABLE Startdate Datetime = '2021-Jun-01 00:00:00.000'
VARIABLE Enddate Datetime = '2021-Jun-30 00:00:00.000' 
EXEC :Startdate := '2021-Jun-30 00:00:00.000'
EXEC :Enddate := '2021-Jun-30 00:00:00.000'

WITH Temp1 as (
select ...
from ...),

/* Unsure about using WHILE with with 2 CTEs so removing them for now but will need to be added*/

WITH Temp2 as
select ...
from (Temp 1)
left join
select ...

set startdate = :startdate + 1

end)

select * from Temp2;
```

The 2 blocks of code work perfectly individually. I think my concern lies with one or all of the following:

1. Variable Declaration - I read a couple of stackoverflow posts and it seems like there is binding variable and substitution variable. Is there a different way to declare variables?
2. The WHILE Loop specially between 2 CTEs. Can we do a while loop as a CTE? (similar to this) [create while loop with cte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929165/create-while-loop-with-cte)
3. How the date is incremented. Is this the proper way to increment dates in Oracle PL/SQL?

Any guidance would be helpful.

Also adding 2 blocks of codes for reference:

Details of Tables:

Transactions - Contains Transaction information. Execution Date is a timestamp of the transaction execution

Account - Contains Account Information with a unique Account_Key for every account

Code_Rel - Maps the transaction code to a transaction type

Group Rel - Maps the transaction type to a transaction group

```
/***Block 1 of Code***/
insert into Temp1
select 
  a.ACCOUNT_KEY
  ,a.SPG_CD
  ,t.EXECUTION_DATE
from Schema_Name.TRANSACTIONS t
inner join Schema_Name.ACCOUNT a on a.en_sk=t.ac_sk
inner join Schema_Name.Code_Rel tr on t.t_cd_s = tr.t_cd_s  
inner join ( select * from Schema_Name.Group_Rel                                                       
                     where gtrt_cd in ('Type1','Type2')) tt on tr.trt_cd = tt.trt_cd
where t.EXECUTION_DATE >= @startdate and  t.EXECUTION_DATE<=@EndDt
and tt.gtrt_cd in ('Type1','Type2')
group by a.ACCOUNT_KEY ,a.SPG_CD, t.EXECUTION_DATE;

/***WHILE LOOP***/
while @startdate <= @EndDt
BEGIN

/***INSERT AND BLOCK 2 OF CODE***/
insert into Temp2
select table1.account_key, table1.SPG_CD, @startdate, coalesce(table2.sum_tr1,0),coalesce(table3.sum_tr2,0),
case when coalesce(table3.sum_tr2,0)>0 THEN coalesce(table2.sum_tr1,0)/coalesce(table3.sum_tr2,0) ELSE 0 END,
case when coalesce(table3.sum_tr2,0)>0 THEN 
       CASE WHEN coalesce(table2.sum_tr1,0)/coalesce(table3.sum_tr2,0)>=0.9 and coalesce(table2.sum_tr1,0)/coalesce(table3.sum_tr2,0)<=1.10 and coalesce(table2.sum_tr1,0)>=1000 THEN 'Yes' else 'No' END 
       ELSE 'No' END
FROM ( SELECT * FROM Temp1 WHERE execution_date=@startdate) TABLE1 LEFT JOIN
(
select a.account_key,a.SPG_CD, SUM(t.AC_Amt) as sum_tr1        
from Schema_Name.TRANSACTIONS t
inner join Schema_Name.ACCOUNT a on a.en_sk=t.ac_sk
inner join Schema_Name.Code_Rel tr on t.t_cd_s = tr.t_cd_s  
inner join ( select * from Schema_Name.Group_Rel                                                       
                     where gtrt_cd in ('Type1')) tt on tr.trt_cd = tt.trt_cd

where t.EXECUTION_DATE <= @startdate 
and t.EXECUTION_DATE >=dateadd(day,-6,@startdate) 
and tt.gtrt_cd in ('Type1') 
group by a.account_key, a.SPG_CD
) table2 ON table1.account_key=table2.account_key
LEFT JOIN
(
select a.account_key,a.SPG_CD, SUM(t.AC_Amt) as sum_tr2        
from Schema_Name.TRANSACTIONS t
inner join Schema_Name.ACCOUNT a on a.en_sk=t.ac_sk
inner join Schema_Name.Code_Rel tr on t.t_cd_s = tr.t_cd_s  
inner join ( select * from Schema_Name.Group_Rel                                                       
                     where gtrt_cd in ('Type2')) tt on tr.trt_cd = tt.trt_cd

where t.EXECUTION_DATE <= @startdate 
and t.EXECUTION_DATE >=dateadd(day,-6,@startdate) 
and tt.gtrt_cd in ('Type2')
group by a.account_key, a.SPG_CD ) table3 on table1.account_key=table3.account_key
where coalesce(table2.sum_tr1,0)>=1000


set @startdate=dateadd(d,1,@startdate)
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use PL/SQL or a `WHILE` loop or to declare variables and can probably do it all in a single SQL query using subquery factoring clauses (and recursion) to generate a calendar of incrementing dates. Something like this made-up example:

```sql
INSERT INTO temp2 (col1, col2, col3)
WITH time_bounds(start_date, end_date) AS (
  -- You can declare the bounds in the query.
  SELECT DATE '2021-06-01',
         DATE '2021-06-30'
  FROM   DUAL
),
calendar (dt, end_date) AS (
  -- Recursive query to generate a row for each day.
  SELECT start_date, end_date FROM time_bounds
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY, end_date
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY <= end_date
),
temp1 (a, b, c) AS (
  -- Made-up query
  SELECT a, b, c FROM some_table
),
temp2 (a, d, e) AS (
  -- Another made-up query.
  SELECT t1.a,
         s2.d,
         s2.e
  FROM   temp1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN some_other_table s2
         ON (t1.b = s2.b)
)
-- Get the values to insert.
SELECT t2.a,
       t2.d,
       t2.e
FROM   temp2 t2
       INNER JOIN calendar c
       ON (t2.e = c.dt)
WHERE  a BETWEEN 3.14159 AND 42;
```

If you try doing it with multiple inserts in a PL/SQL loop then it will be much slower than a single statement.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Definitely looks much cleaner. I am trying to see if this works but the first block of code (marked Temp1) has select * from transactions where execution_date > startdate and execution_date < enddate

I am guessing the calendar increment piece of code will run 30 times for the month. Should I just update the Temp1 code to --- where execution_date = startdate so that it just gets data for the date in our calendar subquery?

Comment: @Dhruv I have no idea as I have not seen you code. Your question replaces all the implementation details with `...` so I have had to make everything up for the answer and guess what your requirements are. If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68667964/edit) your question give details of your tables and an executable query then we can respond.

Comment: Gotcha. I have added the code to my original question. Let me know if it makes more sense now?